# JPA Criteria API and OrderBy on subclasses attributes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api, subclass

I have an **AbstractPerson** wich as two subclasses : **LegalPerson** and **PhysicalPerson**.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractPerson {
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class LegalPerson extends AbstractPerson {
    private String name;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class PhysicalPerson extends AbstractPerson {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    ...
}
```

When I retrieve all my entities (CriteriaQuery based on AbstractPerson) **I would order them by LegalPerson.name ASC, PhysicalPerson.lastName ASC, PhysicalPerson.firstName ASC**.

I need to produce an abstract entities list sorted and grouped by these criterias.
Original SQL query lets appear all subclass fields (SINGLE_TABLE strategy) but I don't know how to exploit them.

**Is there any solution using Criteria API to order the query result on subclasses attributes ?**

Thanks,
Best regards,
Seth.

Answer (score 1):

The Criteira API defines an as() API that allows you to cast to another class.  This should work for subclasses I think, at least with EclipseLink it should.

If they all have a name, you should consider moving the name up into the superclass.  Ordering by a field that is only in a subclass will give an odd order, as you will first get all of the LegalPersons then all of the PhysicalPersons.

Comment: Thanks you James. I tryied but it causes an Invalid key expression : 
`Root<AbstractPerson> root = cq.from(AbstractPerson.class);`
...
`cb.asc(((Path)root.as(LegalPerson.class)).get(LegalPerson_.name))`

Answer (score 0):

I spent several days struggling with polymorphism in JPA criteria. I came to the conclusion that jpa criteria is of no  help when it comes to polymorphic queries.

The best you can achieve is a restriction on a property of a subclass by a rather complicated exists-subquery-construction.

My tip is: Avoid criteria if you can.

If you have a static query maybe you are more lucky with JPQL.

Comment: Hello Nils,
It seems to be true. Criteria is so strongly-typed it should not allow this type of downcast.
Meanwhile, I use a PrePersist and PreUpdate index field in the abstract class. So, I hope there is a JPA 2.0 Criteria solution (as JPA 2.1 treat for example). Thanks.